# Lokups for Javadocs 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

The javadocs lookups for java8 use -param- for the parameters separation where in intellij it uses (param) so every lookup fails in java 8 docs. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is this with the latest IntelliJ (13?)

Comment: yes it is intellij 13.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug (i.e. there is no fix for it). I wasn't able to find a bug report about it, so I have opened one: [IDEA-118970 Java 8 Javadoc for methods not found due to URL syntax change](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118970) Hopefully it gets fixed for 13.0.2.

In the meantime, as a workaround, I wrote an program to parse a Java `api` directory (e.e. `jdkRoot/docs/api`) and convert the new Java 8 syntax in anchors to the previous syntax. After running, just configure your JDK 8 definition to use the modified directory created by the app. It's something I pounded out quickly, so it is possible I missed something. But some quick testing indicates that it works ok.

The app requires Java 7+ and the [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) HTML Parser Library.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


//Using System out since it is a one off utility and to keep dependencies simple
@SuppressWarnings({"CallToPrintStackTrace", "UseOfSystemOutOrSystemErr"})
public class JavaDocParserAndConvert
{
    private static Path API_DIR;
    private static Path OUT_DIR;
    private static final Pattern dashRegex = Pattern.compile("-");

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.length != 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Usage: JavaDocParserAndConvert <path-to-java-api-directory");
                System.out.println("   Example: JavaDocParserAndConvert C:\\java\\jdk8ea\\b121-x64\\docs\\api");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            API_DIR = Paths.get(args[0]);

            if (Files.notExists(API_DIR))
            {
                System.err.println("Specified API Directory does not exist.");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            OUT_DIR = API_DIR.getParent().resolve("api-modified");

            System.out.println("OUT_DIR = " + OUT_DIR);
            if (Files.notExists(OUT_DIR))
            {
                Files.createDirectories(OUT_DIR);
            }

            JavaDocParserAndConvert converter = new JavaDocParserAndConvert();
            converter.execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("FATAL EXCEPTION: " + ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }


    private void execute() throws Exception
    {
        HtmlFileVisitor fileVisitor = new HtmlFileVisitor();
        Files.walkFileTree(API_DIR, fileVisitor);
        fileVisitor.executorService.shutdown();
        fileVisitor.executorService.awaitTermination(6, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }



    class HtmlFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
    {
        private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
        {
            if (file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".html"))
            {
                FileProcessor processor = new FileProcessor(file);
                executorService.submit(processor);
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    }


    static class FileProcessor implements Runnable
    {
        static final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        static final AtomicInteger fileCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final Path file;


        FileProcessor(Path file)
        {
            this.file = file;
        }


        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                final int fileCountValue = fileCount.incrementAndGet();
                if ((fileCountValue % 100) == 0)
                {
                    System.out.printf("File Count: %7s%n", formatter.format(fileCountValue));
                }
                processFile(file);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("An Exception occurred processing file " + file + "  Details: " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }


        public void processFile(Path file) throws IOException
        {
            final Document document = Jsoup.parse(file.toFile(), "UTF-8");
            final Elements anchorElements = document.getElementsByTag("a");

            for (Element anchorElement : anchorElements)
            {
                convertAttr(anchorElement);
            }

            final Path subPath = file.subpath(API_DIR.getNameCount(), file.getNameCount());
            final Path outputFile = OUT_DIR.resolve(subPath);
            final Path dir = outputFile.getParent();
            if (Files.notExists(dir))
            {
                Files.createDirectories(dir);
            }

            Files.deleteIfExists(outputFile);
            Files.createFile(outputFile);

            try (final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFile, Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
            {
                writer.write(document.toString());
            }
        }


        private void convertAttr(Element anchor)
        {
            convertAttr(anchor, "name");
            convertAttr(anchor, "href");
        }


        private void convertAttr(Element anchor, String attrName)
        {
            final String attrValue = anchor.attr(attrName);
            if (!attrValue.isEmpty())
            {
                final String updatedNameAttr = convertAttrValue(attrValue);
                anchor.attr(attrName, updatedNameAttr);
            }
        }


        private String convertAttrValue(String attrValue)
        {
            if (attrValue.endsWith("-"))
            {
                String updated = attrValue;
                updated = dashRegex.matcher(updated).replaceFirst("(");
                updated = updated.substring(0, updated.length() - 1) + ')';
                updated = dashRegex.matcher(updated).replaceAll(", ");
                return updated;
            }
            else
            {
                return attrValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```